# Updating a cell value after each ajax success

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I need to append a new sum of payment in a form. I have in my table a cell:

```
<th id="final_cash"><?php echo $sumCash ?> $</th>
```

This cell should be updated after each success call of ajax script.

```
success:function(res)
            {
                //if(res=="added")
                //{
                    alert("information added");
                    $(document).find('input[type=text]').val('');
                    $(document).find('input[type=date]').val('');
                    $(document).find('select').val('0');
          if(pay_type="cash")
          {
            var fcash = $("#final_cash").text();
            fcash = parseInt(fcash);
            console.log(fcash);
            var total = fcash+project_cost;
            console.log(total);
            $("#after_tr").after("<tr><td>"+project_desc+"</td><td>"+prescription+"</td><td>"+ext+"</td><td>"
              +doo+"</td><td>"+endo+"</td><td>"+fm+"</td><td>"
              +crown+"</td><td>"+rmvbl+"</td><td>"+paro+"</td><td>"+date_pay+"</td><td>"+project_cost+"</td></tr>")
            $("#final_cash").val("");
            console.log(fcash);
            $("#final_cash").text(total);
          }
```

I am parsing to int because cell conatain `$` and I just need the integer.
the final result of the sum per example if the old value is 1400 and the new value that should be added is 600 is like `1400600` instead of `2000`.

[image]

Comment: What doesn't work ? `$('#final_cash').text(total);` should work.

Comment: I am getting 1400600 instead of the sum

Comment: it should be `1400+600 = 2000` but I am getting 1400600

Comment: Use `parseInt()` on fcash and project_cost?

Comment: `project_cost` already defined in the ajax script why I should parse it too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`project_cost` seems to be handled as a string.
You can use `parseInt()` on `project_cost` like theblackgigant suggested in the comments or you can use the unary plus operator.

```
var total = fcost + +project_cost
```

The unary plus operator converts any string to its numeric value.
You could even do something like this:

```
var total = +fcost + +project_cost
```

Then you don't need to call `parseInt()` at all.